# Insert a PHP constant into a string

Tags: php, string-concatenation

I have this file called db.php which makes the connection to the database.

```
<?php
    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_NAME", "login");
    define("DB_USER", "admin");
    define("DB_PASS", "123");
    mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) OR die("Falha na ligação.");
?>
```

What I wanted to do is to use that DB_NAME define in another file so that I just need to change it in the db.php in case I have to change the database name.

Here's an example of where I want it to be aplied.

```
$qp = "UPDATE login.users SET palpiteatual = '".$_POST['atextfield']."' WHERE user_name = '".$_SESSION['user_name']."'";
```

Instead of having login.users, I tried this following ways without succeeding.

```
$qp = "UPDATE '"DB_NAME"'.users SET palpiteatual = '".$_POST['atextfield']."' WHERE user_name = '".$_SESSION['user_name']."'";
$qp = "UPDATE "+DB_NAME+".users SET palpiteatual = '".$_POST['atextfield']."' WHERE user_name = '".$_SESSION['user_name']."'";
```

Not sure how is the exact syntax to use it this way. Thanks in advance

Comment: what syntax error are you getting?

Comment: When you have connected to 'login' database, then why do you still need to specify database name?

Comment: Since you are still using the [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) mysql_ function, please at least use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to avoid SQL injection through form inputs. Or better yet, upgrade to [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and prepare and execute your statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$qp = "UPDATE ".DB_NAME.".users SET palpiteatual...";
```

Note that, if you don't have multiple connection and multiple database, no need to use DB_NAME

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation in PHP is done with [the concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) `.`

```
$qp = "UPDATE ".DB_NAME.".users
```